# Transfer Azure batch windows container task output file to batch task working directory fails

Tags: docker-volume, azure-batch, windows-container

I am prototyping an azure batch sample using windows container workload in batch task. This container expects an input file, executes an algorithm and writes an output file st01_demo_results.csv inside the container at path C:\app\output (this directory is created in dockerfile build). On batch task success, the output file will be uploaded to azure storage container using SAS URL. I have mostly used [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/batch-dotnet-ffmpeg-tutorial) to build my prototype, just that instead of using exe, I am using windows container.
I am trying to transfer my output file generated inside windows container to batch task working directory by mounting a volume with source as batch task working directory and target my container output file path.

```
string taskCommandLine = $"{inputMediaFile} C:\\app\\output\\{outputMediaFile}";
string containerRunOptions = "-v %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR%:c:\\app\\output:rw";
```

```
    var task = new CloudTask(taskId, taskCommandLine)
    {
      UserIdentity = new UserIdentity(autoUserSpec),
      ContainerSettings = containerSettings,
    };
    task.ResourceFiles = new List<ResourceFile> { inputFiles[i] };
```

With this, I get exception
`Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\app\output\st01_demo_results.csv' is denied.`

If, I don't provide volume binding in containerRunOptions then my container task executes fine but then I don't get the file transferred to my batch task working directory.
I suspect, that azure batch somewhere ignores `rw` option and forcefully makes the volume binding read-only - because when I tried running the same windows container locally in docker desktop with `ro` option, I get same unauthorized exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `c:\\app\\output` is accessible by the container user that is currently executing within the container context, typically `ContainerUser`, `ContainerAdministrator`, or some custom user that you may have added as part of your `DOCKERFILE`.